# decode self.request.body

Tags: python, google-app-engine, wsgi

In my post handler, the body of the message is a json.
In self.request.body, I'm getting a HTML encoded message:

```
%7B+%22name%22%3A+%22John+Dao%22%2C+%22Age%22%3A+42+%7D=
```

Taking a look at the network traffic, the payload is actually:

```
{ "name": "John Dao", "Age": 42 }
```

So, I'm pretty sure the encoding happens on the server. How do I decode this string, or somehow tell json.loads to accept encoded message, or better yet - tell WSGI (It is Google App Engine) not encoding the body to beging with?

Comment: Check urlparse.unquote. You may need to replace plus signs with spaces.

Comment: What content-type are you sending your body with? If you're using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, that may be causing the encoding. Also, @rubik, I think you're thinking of `urllib.unquote`, and `urllib.unquote_plus` handles pluses.

Comment: @Nick, you are correct. Setting Content-Type to 'application/json' makes GAE not encoding anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.unquote_plus("%7B+%22name%22%3A+%22John+Dao%22%2C+%22Age%22%3A+42+%7D=")
'{ "name": "John Dao", "Age": 42 }='
```

It looks as though the GAE implementation of WebOb is trying to parse and rewrite the POST body as though its content type is "application/x-www-urlencoded" - even the url-decoded string has a "=" appended to it.

If this is the case, and you can change the client behavior, try setting it to something like "application/json" instead.

Comment: Thank you @akgood. Having 'Content-Type: application/json' on the client did fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to get the values corresponding to the keys `name` and `Age`, you can simple call `self.request.get('name')` and `self.request.get('Age')`. If the key is not found it will return an empty string by default.

Comment: See my comment on the original post.